# SDK style project: Determine what triggered project build

Tags: msbuild

Back with the plain old non-SDK style `.csproj` format, if you run a build with verbosity set to `Diagnostic`, the 1. line of the build output told you why a certain project got built in that build.

Like:

```
Project '<project name>' is not up to date.
Input file '<static file>' is modified after output file ''.`
```

Or:

```
Project '<project name>' is not up to date.
CopyLocal reference source '<dll from package>' is more recent than '<dll in bin folder>'.
```

This very useful feature seems to be lost now with SDK style projects; there is no such information logged anymore.
Builds start with smg like:

```
Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'...
```

We have a dependent project which always got rebuilt, no matter there were no changes affecting it.

How can I figure out what's causing that SDK style project to be always rebuilt?